# adding header and footer for html2pdf

Tags: html, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2pdf

```
  download() {
      var element = document.getElementById("element-to-print");

      html2pdf()
        .from(element)
        .set({
          margin: [25, 15, 15, 15],
          filename: '<?=$fname;?> as <?=trim(date("dmY"));?>.pdf',
          image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas: {
            scale: 2,
            logging: true,
            dpi: 192,
            letterRendering: true,
          },
          jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "p" },
          pagebreak: { before: ".page-break", avoid: "table" },

          header: {
            height: "20mm",
            contents: function (page, totalPages) {
              // Generate header content here
              return '<div style="text-align: center;">Header Content</div>';
            },
          },
          footer: {
            height: "15mm",
            contents: function (page, totalPages) {
              // Generate footer content here
              return (
                '<div style="text-align: center;">Footer Content - Page ' +
                page +
                " of " +
                totalPages +
                "</div>"
              );
            },
          },
        })
        .toPdf()
        .get("pdf")
        .then(function (pdf) {
          var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
          for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            pdf.setPage(i);
            pdf.setFontSize(8);
            pdf.setTextColor(150);
            pdf.text(0, 10, "[SULIT]");
            pdf.text(
              'Tarikh Cetakan: <?=trim(date("d/m/Y h:i A"));?> | Mukasurat: ' +
                i +
                "/" +
                totalPages +
                "",
              pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 85,
              pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 7
            );
          }
        })
        .save();
    },
```

I am trying to create `pdf` using `html2pdf`. In the given example the header and footer is `text.` instead of `text`. Is there any way to include `HTML` part as header and footer? To make my `pdf` more specific.

Comment: As per my previous experiments, html2pdf does not specifically does not help with header and footer html styles. Best is that you convert separate elements for header html and footer toImg and addImage to the PDF.